# bigcommerce stencil start error: "The BigCommerce server responded with a 500 error"

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

The stencil version i uesed is 1.2.2,the command 'stencil start' was work well a few days ago,but tody when i run 'stencil start' ,there is a error :

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: Error: The BigCommerce server responded with a 500 error
    at C:\Users\Administrator.USER-20160426SD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@
bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js:42:31
    at C:\Users\Administrator.USER-20160426SD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@
bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js:133:20
    at finish (C:\Users\Administrator.USER-20160426SD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\wreck\lib\index.js:137:20)
    at wrapped (C:\Users\Administrator.USER-20160426SD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:866:20)
    at ClientRequest.onResponse (C:\Users\Administrator.USER-20160426SD\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\wreck\lib\index.j
s:158:20)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:426:21
)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:317:20)
```

I tried several times,it aways the same error .Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the store you have it pointed to?

Comment: Maybe, I point it to another store ,it can run successfully.I wonder why the first store is wrong

Comment: The first store is a free trial I applied for yesterday,

Comment: If that free trial is in pre-launch mode, that could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer would help.

If you have selected Blueprint theme at Store SetUp --> Design and running Stencil locally. It will throw 500 error.

Try to select any stencil free theme at Store Setup --> Design. And then run the command(stencil start).

It will Work. :)